# What function preserve the state of a tree?

Tags: jquery

I used `treeview` to render my tree after clicking a menu within it :

```
$("#browser").treeview({
    collapsed: true,
    animated: "fast",
    prerendered: false
});
```

The problem is that opened submenus are collapsed. So how to preserve the state of the menu ? What other functions , other than `treeview` can be used for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

treeview doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, there are other libraries that do the same but are more recent

- http://www.jstree.com/
- http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/

hope this helps